# Error while Installing hyperledger composer getting build error

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

While installing hyperledger composer, using npm -v5.0.4 & node -v8.15.0, got following error:

user@gaurav-toora-XL-01:~$ npm install -g composer-cli@0.20
/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/bin/composer -> /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/cli.js

> dtrace-provider@0.8.7 install /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider
>   node-gyp rebuild || node suppress-error.js

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-141-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/bin/node" "/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider
gyp ERR! node -v v8.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

> node-report@2.2.1 install /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-141-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/bin/node" "/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report
gyp ERR! node -v v8.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-report@2.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-report@2.2.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2019-02-28T13_21_56_249Z-debug.log
```

Comment: have you tried to install using npm 6.x?

Comment: Yes i had tried with npm 6.4.1, but getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install using Node version 8.9.x